# ASP.NET GridView throws: The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'date'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

How to deal with a server that doesn't support 'date'? Sorry for such a vague question. Please let me know what addtional details I should add. Thanks.

Here's the error:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'date'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'date'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

---

For the Column Properties from the server explorer, I've specified the column as a **datetime**, so I'm not sure why the auto generated ASP.NET gridview is trying to work with a **date** type as opposed to a datetime type.

[image]

Here's the code auto-generated by the ASP.NET 2.0 grid view that is causing the error:

[image]

Is it okay to just change DbType="Date" to DbType="Datetime"? (It seems to work.)

Comment: how did you manage to get to this point? :-) Almost seems as if the SQL data source assumes you're using SQL Server 2008 for some reason.... can you explain the steps? What tools / wizards / black magic did you use?

Comment: From the Visual Studio 2008 Server Explorer, I dragged the Contacts table onto a ASP.NET 2.0 webform in the designer. Then, configuring the sql datasource which is auto-magically created, I elected to "Generate Insert, Update, and Delete statements".  This all generates a grid view control with Insert, Update, and Delete links in the left-most column of the grid view control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you are looking for either the [`datetime` or `smalldatetime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277(SQL.80).aspx) type:

> Date and time data types for representing date and time of day

Comment: Is it okay to just change DbType="Date" to DbType="Datetime"?

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a user-defined type based on DateTime that always has a time component equal to 0 (aka midnight).

Comment: I would recommend against creating custom data types. Lots of articles on why this is not such a good idea. Also UDTs may be discontinued in the future.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server pre-2008 does not support just `DATE` like Oracle (and some other RDBMS).

You are probably looking at `DateTime` or `SmallDateTime`

Most of us use either one of those - we just leave the time part as `00:00:00`.

Comment: Is it okay to just change DbType="Date" to DbType="Datetime"?

Comment: @Raj: SQL Server 2008 does have a `DATE` type. Earlier versions don't.