# Converting getdate() to yyyymmdd & getting the date two years back

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have found a couple of different methods to convert it. However, I still get the `yyyy-mm-dd` format or `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. I am currently using SQL Server 2014.

```
SELECT dateadd(day, convert(int, getdate()), 112)
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, -2, convert(DATE, GETDATE(), 112))
```

I am doing a date range of 2 years. Thus I need the codes to the find the date two years back.

Comment: and specify what DBMS

Comment: @HoneyBadger I have tried 'SELECT dateadd(day, convert(int, getdate()), 112)' & 'SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, -2, convert(DATE, GETDATE(), 112))'. Both do not convert into a yyyymmdd

Comment: @GiladGreen I am currently suing SQL Server 2014

Comment: Looks like you want a `datetime` datatype returned. These don't have a format, if you want a specific format displayed, you'll have to convert to a string datatype (eg `VARCHAR`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server getdate() to a string like "2009-12-20"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937101/sql-server-getdate-to-a-string-like-2009-12-20)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can also use FORMAT:

```
 select FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyyMMdd')
```

Comment: why do I get "20160025"? seems rather weird.

Comment: Try now, with yyyyMMdd instead of yyyymmdd

Comment: yup it works now. Thanks for the codes man. If it isn't too much, could you help me with the codes to get the date two years back?

Comment: @Brandon SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(YEAR, -2, getdate()), 'yyyyMMdd')

Answer (score 4):

Try `CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112)`

Also check https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot man. This is the code I am looking for. If it isn't too much, how do I get the date for 2 years back?

Comment: `dateadd(year, -2, getdate());`

Comment: Would it be possible to take out the time? Also the date format is not what i requested.

Comment: @Brandon Yes it is possible.